Could the shuttle have avoided the umbilical plate if the LH2 and LOx had been piped directly to the nozzles?
One of the riskier components of the Shuttle's design (that fortunately never failed) are the umbilical doors on the rear underside of the orbiter.
There are probably aerodynamic and structural reasons for this, but I was wondering if it was possible to have the fuel and oxidizer piped on the exterior of the vehicle, maybe with some sort of detachable or permanent piping assembly.
I'm sure that would be a difficult and unreasonable design, but I'm wondering what specifically wouldn't work with it? I would think NASA would not have introduced the extra risk imposed by umbilical door failure without good reason, especially considering that, according to an astronaut, they had not developed a realistic procedure for manually closing them on orbit if that was required.

The Shuttle's hydrogen and oxygen tanks are not inside the orbiter. As long as that is the case, you will need a connection between the external tank and the orbiter.
The only other location for those connections that makes any sense is the rear bulkhead through which the engines are inserted. But having a pipe there means it has to go around the aft body flap, which means the pipe is exposed to the engine exhaust, or perpendicular to the airflow. Neither is a good option.
Having the entry in that location also means the pipe is exposed to the very hot gases of the main engine exhaust. and you have to get rid of that pipe before reentry, which means you have to jettison it, and have it move between the exhaust nozzles and the aft body flap, both of which are fragile.
